# Caracteres Especiais C# e MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela de municípios dentro do sistema, base de dados MS SQL Server, e os nomes dos municípios estão com acentos.

Eu estou consumindo uma API onde os municípios vem sem nenhuma acentuação, com isso o select não funciona por causa destas diferenças.

Eu criei um select com a função replace do MSSQL e quando eu executo diretamente pelo query do MSSQL o select funciona.

select que coloquei dentro da aplicação

```
SELECT OCNT."AbsId"
FROM OCNT
WHERE
REPLACE(OCNT."NAME",'ã','a') = 'Sao Paulo'
```

Se eu utilizo este mesmo select na aplicação a mesma não funciona, eu liguei o profile do MSSQL e capturei o select, ele muda o select e eu sinceramente não sei o motivo que ele faz a troca.

Abaixo o select que peguei do profile do MSSQL

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,NULL,N'SELECT OCNT."AbsId"
, [OCNT].AbsId AS ''kEY_AbsId'' 
FROM OCNT
WHERE
REPLACE(OCNT."NAME",''Ã£'',''a'') = ''SAO PAULO''
 FOR BROWSE '
select @p1
```

De forma alguma eu posso dar UPDATE na base de dados para tirar os caracteres por se tratar de sistema proprietario, o que me limita de criar views, funções e stored procedures.

Queria saber se alguem já passou por isso e como contornar.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa fazer `REPLACE` explícito, o `SQL SERVER` tem [o COLLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) que pode fazer isso direto no resultado da query. Ele é um *statement* que pode ser usado no comando `SELECT`, assim:

```
SELECT OCNT."AbsId"
  FROM OCNT
 WHERE OCNT."NAME" = 'Sao Paulo' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI;
```

Mais informações sobre `COLLATE`, unicode ou outros tipos: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Veja um exemplo aqui funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b3bf7d/1

Comment: Pefeito... Funcionou como eu queria. Obrigado